# Update Error: Navigation property Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.SongCategories'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SongCategories'. The duplicate key value is (2, 3).
>   The statement has been terminated.

I am trying to let users edit the song **and** the navigation properties.

```
public class Song 
{
    //AudioName, Artist etc
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
```

EF creates a SongCategories table from this with the columns `Song_Id` and `Category_Id`.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestEdit(EditSongDto editSongDto)
 {
      var categories = _categoryService.GetCategories().Where(x => editSongDto.SelectedCategoryIds.Any(z => z == x.Id));
      _songService.Edit(_songService.GetSong(editSongDto.Song.Id), editSongDto.AudioName, editSongDto.ArtistName, categories);   
}
```

Service:

```
public void Edit(Song song, string audioName, string artistName, IEnumerable<Category> categories)
{
    song.AudioName = audioName;
    song.ArtistName = artistName;

    song.Categories = categories.ToList();

    _repository.Edit(song);
}
```

Repository:

```
public virtual void Edit(T entity)
{
   _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
   Save();
}
```

This happens when the and the same one gets passed in again. How can I update the navigation properties properly? I have looked at other threads but still do not know the answer.

Comment: Have you tried?

_song.Categories.Clear();_
_song.Categories = categories.ToList();_

Comment: @robinet Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks a lot. If you want points I will accept an answer. I presumed I didn't need to clear because the assignment would overwrite it. I guess it has something to do with proxy tracking still.

Comment: I've been having some headaches with EF lately :D. I'll add an answer if you want to mark it as such, no worries anyway, I've come here for help like you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is tricky with Many-to-Many relationships. I believe it doesn't have a change to lazy load `song.Categories` before you overwrite it with `categories.ToList()` so it's unaware of existing `song-Category` relationships

By calling `song.Categories.Clear()`, you force lazy loading and explicitly state that existing `song-Category` relationships are to be deleted for that particular song. Next you assign the new relationships by overwriting the `Categories` collection and EF "fixes up" everything to generate the correct `INSERT/DELETE` statements

```
public void Edit(Song song, string audioName, string artistName, IEnumerable<Category> categories)
{
    song.AudioName = audioName;
    song.ArtistName = artistName;

    song.Categories.Clear();
    song.Categories = categories.ToList();

    _repository.Edit(song);
}
```

Maybe a better way is to iterate over `song.Categories` removing what is not contained in the new category list and then adding from the category list what is not in the `song.Categories` but I haven't tested it myself